# Variable affectation from function not working with $()

Tags: bash

I'm trying to define a function which behaviour that will, the first time it has been called, ask the user for some choice and then remember thoses choice in order not to ask the user again.

Using a variable to store the state (initialized or not) works well when the function is called the normal way, however if I want this function to return results, capturing thoses results with `$()` breaks the behaviour I'm trying to achieve

Here is a simple reproductible exemple:

```
#!/bin/bash
initialized=false
function givevalue
{
    echo "init = $initialized" 1>&2
    if ! $initialized;
    then
        echo "a b c"
        initialized=true
    else
        echo "d e f"
    fi
}
for i in $(givevalue); do echo "run 1 : $i"; done
for i in $(givevalue); do echo "run 2 : $i"; done
```

the result I get is

```
init = false
run 1 : a
run 1 : b
run 1 : c
init = false
run 2 : a
run 2 : b
run 2 : c
```

while I was expecting

```
init = false
run 1 : a
run 1 : b
run 1 : c
init = true
run 2 : d
run 2 : e
run 2 : f
```

Comment: See Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer for the reason your code fails. A simple workaround is to not have your function _echo_ the stuff to be reused, but have it _set a return variable_. Then you'll call your function and use this variable: `givevalue() { ... initialized=true ... givevalue_ret="a b c"; }` and then use as: `givevalue; for i in $givevalue_ret; do ...`. Using this design, you'll be able to have the return of `givevalue` be an _array_! you'll gain a lot by doing that: your loop will be much cleaner and safer; it'll be more efficient too, since you won't spawn a subshell.

Comment: that is what i'm doing. Sure it's safer, but from my functional point of view I don't find this cleaner in any way

Comment: Forget functional programming in Bash. And actually your paradigm _isn't_ functional at all since you have clear side effects.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: s/have clear side effects/Want to have clear side effects/. The problem is precisely that the environment mutation is ephemeral, so it's at least questionable as to whether `$(givevalue)` can be considered to have a side effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of `$(...)` are run as a separate process and changes to variables are not propagated to the parent shell. This cannot be changed.